# Copying a file via ssh

Tags: ssh, networking

I am trying to copy a file over from my machine to my personal space on a university server. On my machine, the file is located at `/home/karnivaurus/file.pdf`.

If I connect to the server with `ssh karnivaurus@server.uni.ac.uk`, and then run `pwd`, it prints `/homes/karnivaurus`. If I run `ls`, it just displays one directory, `foo`.  What I want to do then, is to copy this file over to the directory `/homes/karnivaurus/foo`.

So, after exiting the ssh, I enter the local home directory `/home/karnivaurus`. I then run the command `cp paper.pdf karnivaurus@server.uni.ac.uk/foo/paper.pdf`, but this returns the error message `cp: failed to access ‘karnivaurus@shell1.doc.ic.ac.uk/homes/karnivaurus/paper.pdf’: Not a directory`. I have also tried running `cp paper.pdf karnivaurus@server.uni.ac.uk/homes/karnivaurus/foo/paper.pdf`, but this gives me the same error message.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The comamnd is `scp` and not `cp`.  `cp` only copies files locally on the same machine; `scp` copies files via `ssh`.

Comment: Crossposted here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/808507/copying-a-file-via-ssh

Answer (score 1):

Like already mentioned by  Stephen Harris, you need to use `scp`, not `cp`.

The correct, minimal syntax is: `scp user@maschine:/path/to/source/file user@maschine:/path/to/destination/file`.

For your example, if you are on your local machine, the following should do:

```
scp /home/karnivaurus/file.pdf karnivaurus@server.uni.ac.uk:/homes/karnivaurus/foo
```